# Log4j JMS appender sends empty message to STOMP client

Tags: node.js, log4j, jms, activemq-classic, stomp

Am using log4j JMS appender to forward log messages. And am running a Node JS using STOMP-CLIENT , to listen to activemq, to receive the forwarded log messages

The problem now is, whenever the log is forwarded, the message is received as empty

This is my stomp client code

```
var Stomp = require('stomp-client');
var destination = '/topic/logTopic';
var client = new Stomp('127.0.0.1', 61613, '', '');
client.connect(function(sessionId) {
    client.subscribe(destination, function(body, headers) {     
        console.log('Mesage');
      console.log(body); //This is empty
    });       

});
```

This is my Log4.j properties

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, stdout, jms

## Be sure that ActiveMQ messages are not logged to &#39;jms&#39; appender
log4j.logger.org.apache.activemq=INFO, stdout

log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d %-5p %c - %m%n

## Configure &#39;jms&#39; appender. You&#39;ll also need jndi.properties file in order to make it work
log4j.appender.jms=org.apache.log4j.net.JMSAppender
log4j.appender.jms.InitialContextFactoryName=org.apache.activemq.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory
log4j.appender.jms.ProviderURL=tcp://localhost:61616
log4j.appender.jms.TopicBindingName=logTopic
log4j.appender.jms.TopicConnectionFactoryBindingName=ConnectionFactory
```

Comment: Did you check the topic messages in the ActiveMQ admin web interface? Are the message bodies visible there?

Comment: I'm seeing something very similar.  The issue isn't STOMP though, it's my Logback client.  (Using the Queue Browser, the messages are empty)

Answer (score 0):

Try to set:

```
<bean class="org.apache.activemq.util.XStreamFactoryBean" name="xstream">
     <property name="annotatedClass"> 
            <value>org.apache.activemq.transport.stomp.SamplePojo</value>
     </property>
</bean>
```

http://activemq.2283324.n4.nabble.com/Active-MQ-sends-empty-message-bodies-via-Stomp-td2364203.html